# Why use the same basis for domain and codomain of linear operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

(All of this over finite dimensional vector spaces) In Artin, Algebra, Chapter 4, section 3., the author says "When we are dealing with linear operators. It is clear that we want to pick only one basis for $V$". Why is it clear? In the page before, it was proved that for any linear transformation you can choose basis in domain and codomain so it's matrix takes the block form $\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. This at first sounds very desirable to work with. If we use the same basis, the best we can do is Jordan Canonical form, which is nowhere as simple. So why restrict ourselves to use the same basis? It doesn't seem "clear" at all.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with linear operators you want to take sums, scalar multiples, compositions. Having new bases every time would be a nightmare.

Even with a single operator $T$, saying that its composition with itself, $T^2$, is again $\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ at the cost of furnishing yet a new basis, gives you no benefit.

Also, the Jordan form is a lot better than the Smith form: having the eigenvalues and their multiplicities visible, as well as some eigenvectors, is way better than hiding them in a contrived basis.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the actual context of that quote, but my guess
is that it refers to maps from a vector space to itself. In
that case, the composition of these maps makes sense. Using
one basis for the vector space associates a square matrix to
the maps where composition of maps corresponds to product
of matrices. If there is a different basis used for the
codomain, then this association is not possible. Given this
context, it makes little sense to use another basis for the
same vector space.

Another reason is that choosing a basis allows us to define
the matrix of the linear map and the properties of the map
can be determined from the matrix. In the case you mention
choosing different basis for domain and codomain producing
a block matrix, all of the information about the map is lost
except the dimensions of its domain and its image.